# What is necessary for a function to be able to take stacked NumPy arguments?

Tags: python, numpy

While plotting with a meshgrid defined like this:

```
Y,X = np.mgrid[-5:5:20j, -5:5:20j]
```

For example this function

```
def polynomial(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2
```

can handle `polynomial(X,Y)` but not

```
stack = np.dstack((X,Y))
polynomial(stack)

--->
Type error: polynomial missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

while on the other hand e.g. the pdf of SciPy.stats multivariate_normal

```
mu = [0,0]
sigma = [[3,2]
         [2,3]]
normal = st.multivariate_normal(mu, sigma)
normal = normal.pdf
```

can't handle

```
normal(X,Y)

--->
Type error: pdf() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

but it can handle `normal(stack)`. Both are functions of two variables but the way they accept arguments is apparantly very different.

What changes would I have to make to polynomial such that it can accept stacked arguments like `normal` can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the array shapes:

```
In [165]: Y,X = np.mgrid[-5:5:20j, -5:5:20j]
In [166]: Y.shape
Out[166]: (20, 20)
In [167]: X.shape
Out[167]: (20, 20)
```

That's 2 arrays.  Joining them on a new trailing axis:

```
In [168]: stack = np.dstack((X,Y))
In [169]: stack.shape
Out[169]: (20, 20, 2)
```

An alternative way, with a new leading axis:

```
In [170]: stack1 = np.stack((X,Y))
In [171]: stack1.shape
Out[171]: (2, 20, 20)
```

`ogrid` makes a `sparse` pair:

```
In [172]: y,x = np.ogrid[-5:5:20j, -5:5:20j]
In [173]: y.shape
Out[173]: (20, 1)
In [174]: x.shape
Out[174]: (1, 20)
```

Your `function` can handle these, since they behave the same as `X` and `Y` with respect to broadcasting operators like +:

```
In [175]: def polynomial(x,y):
     ...:     return x**2 + y**2
     ...: 
In [176]: polynomial(x,y).shape
Out[176]: (20, 20)
```

The stacked arrays can be used via:

```
In [177]: polynomial(stack[...,0],stack[...,1]).shape
Out[177]: (20, 20)
In [178]: polynomial(stack1[0],stack1[1]).shape
Out[178]: (20, 20)
```

The function takes 2 arrays - that's explicit in the definition.

The signature of `pdf` is (from the docs)

```
pdf(x, mean=None, cov=1, allow_singular=False)

x : array_like
    Quantiles, with the last axis of `x` denoting the components.
```

It doesn't accept a second positional argument, though you can specify added keyword ones.  How it handles the dimensions of `x` is internal to the function (not part of its signature), but presumably the `dstack` grid works, with "2 components".

Each function has its own signature.  You can't presume that the pattern for one applies to another.  Keep the **docs** at hand!

digging further, `pdf` passes the `x` though a function that

```
Adjust quantiles array so that last axis labels the components of
    each data point.
```

This function definition should handle both the forms (not tested):

```
def polynomial(x,y=None):
    if y is None:
        x, y = x[...,0], x[...,1]
    return x**2 + y**2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I understand correctly this is a way to call `polynomial` on a stacked argument by slicing the argument before/during the call. What would really interest me though is how I could adapt the function definition of polynomial such that it can accept `stack` from the get-go.

Comment: You have to write code within `polynomial` that does that split.  I find that `pdf` passes the `x` through a `_process_quantiles` function that standardizes its shape., and so on.  I added a preliminary variation on your function that should handle both styles of input.